# How can I count the number of words in a sentence using c#? I am just starting to learn this language

Tags: c#

```
    {
        // This program counts the number of words in a sentence
        Console.WriteLine("Write a sentence.");
        string sentence = Console.ReadLine();           
    }
```

Now, how can i count the no. of words in the sentence?

Comment: A sentence is a series of words delimited by spaces and other non-alphabetical characters. Do you know how to split a string?  Not sure which part you’re stuck on.

Comment: Please include what you have already tried, add some code to describe the methods you have implemented to achieve what you want. The question does not contain sufficient detail for people to assist you. As there are several ways in which to resolve your problem. Edit your question to include more detail on what exactly you are trying to achieve and what doesn't work then people will be able to assist better.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would just to use [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_) and get the `Length` of the resulting *array*

> Splits a string into substrings based on the characters in an array.
>   You can specify whether the substrings include empty array elements.

```
string sentence = Console.ReadLine(); 
var array= sentence.Split(new []{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
```

However it depends what you class as word. I.e is a number a word?.